# Which test should I perform?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have 2 datasets. Dataset X looks like this:

```
Jmp_o   Nws_r
1       0
0       1
1       1
0       1
0       1
1       0
1       0
...    ...
```

I calculate the conditional probability P(jmp_o=1|nws_r=1). There is another dataset Y which is like:

```
Jmp_o   Nws_r
1       0
0       0
1       0
0       0
0       0
1       0
1       0
...    ...
```

From dataset Y I calculate unconditional probability P(jmp_o=1).

I want to test whether these 2 probabilities are statistically different (by means of p-value).

What test should I perform?

Further clarification: first I have dataset X from where I calculate the conditional probability. Then from dataset X I create a subsample which has Nws_r=0. After creating dataset Y, I calculate the unconditional probability. Now I need to check whether they are different.

Comment: I don't know why the datasets look like that! I'm posting an excel sheet.

Answer (score 3):

If data can be assumed all independent, you can use a standard test to compare two proportions (prop.test in R with references on its help page), where in the first sample you only use the observations for which nws_r=1.

Comment: Would you please tell what test it would be for SAS? and any help on the code?

Comment: To further clarify, first I have dataset X from where I calculate the conditional probability. Then from dataset X I create a subsample which has Nws_r=0. After creating dataset Y, I calculate the unconditional probability. Now I need to check whether they are different.

Comment: For help with SAS code please see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software.